# npm install fails with "Permission denied" and "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors

Tags: node.js, npm, pouchdb

Trying to globally install pouchdb-server on a DO Ubuntu instance (npm install -g pouchdb-server). I'm logged in as the `root` user.

Looks like the heart of the issue is I'm getting a bunch of these:

```
sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
sh: 1: prebuild-install: Permission denied
sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
```

and ultimately failing with:

`npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Here's the full console output:

https://gist.github.com/rmisio/80037764cfe64eb5f2a481cfe56b4b68

FWIW, among dozens of things I've tried, I did individually, globally install the three packages failing with 'Permission denied' errors and they installed without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ::

```
npm config set user 0

npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

It worked for me

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I only needed `npm config set user 0` and all the node-gyp permission denied issues went away.